# Rolle von "bloß, "nur" und "lediglich" bei den irrealen Wunschsätzen

Tags: word-usage

Welche Rolle spielen die Wörter "bloß", "nur" und "lediglich" bei den irrealen Wunschsätzen im Konjunktiv II? z.B:

> Wenn ich nur ein Auto hätte!

Und gibt es Unterschiede zwischen ihnen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sowohl *bloß* als auch *nur* gibt es als **Partikel** und als **Adverb**. *lediglich* gibt es lediglich [sic] als Adverb. Von daher gibt es für die zwei Gruppen unterschiedliche Anwendungen.

**1. Verwendung als Partikeln**

> Wenn ich nur ein Auto hätte!
>
> Wenn ich bloß ein Auto hätte!

Sind sehr ähnlich und unterscheiden sich in dieser Anwendung als Partikeln praktisch nicht. Es wird ausgedrückt, dass der Wunsch ja klein und vernünftig ist und man ihn sich aber trotzdem nicht erfüllen kann, es handelt sich um den Ausdruck der *Verstärkung* des Wunsches.

> Mach das bloß nicht – das ist gefährlich!

Ist eine andere Anwendung als Partikel als Verstärkung einer Aufforderung.

**2. Verwendung als Adverb**

> <s>Wenn ich lediglich ein Auto hätte!</s>

Funktioniert natürlich nicht richtig – *lediglich* ist nicht als Partikel verwendbar, sondern nur als Adverb. Dann kann man es verwenden, um z. B. Aktionen zu verkleinern, die man getan haben sollte, aber nicht getan hat:

> Er hätte [lediglich|bloß|nur] einen Rettungswagen anrufen müssen und das Opfer wäre nicht gestorben.

In der adverbialen Anwendung sind damit alle drei Vokabeln praktisch bedeutungsgleich.

*lediglich* ist allerdings, wie die meisten Verbindungen mit *ledig*, sehr ungebräuchlich geworden. Es wird in der Umgangssprache fast gar nicht mehr, im Juristendeutsch aber noch häufig genutzt. Ein Jurist würde andrerseits wahrscheinlich niemals *bloß* oder *nur* im obigen Beispiel verwenden.